# bulletproof use of from_chars()

Tags: c++, c++17

I have some literal strings which I want to convert to integer and even double. The base is 16, 10, 8, and 2.
At this time, I wonder about the behavior of [std::from_chars()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) - I try to convert and the error code inside `from_chars_result` return holds success - even if it isn't as shown here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <charconv>

using namespace std::literals::string_view_literals;

int main()
{
    auto const buf = "01234567890ABCDEFG.FFp1024"sv;
    double d;

    auto const out = std::from_chars(buf.begin(), buf.end(), d, std::chars_format::hex);
    if(out.ec != std::errc{} || out.ptr != buf.end())
    {
        std::cerr << buf << '\n'
                  << std::string(std::distance(buf.begin(), out.ptr), ' ') << "^- here\n";
        auto const ec = std::make_error_code(out.ec);
        std::cerr << "err: " << ec.message() << '\n';
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << d << '\n';
}
```

gives:

```
01234567890ABCDEFG.FFp1024
                 ^- here
err: Success
```

For convenience also at [coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7466fa299fb56118).

In my use case, I'll check the character set before but, I'm not sure about the checks to make it bulletproof. Is this behavior expected (maybe my English isn't sufficient, or I didn't read carefully enough)? I've never seen such checks on iterators on blogs etc.

The other question is related to different base like 2 and 8. Base of 10 and 16 seems to be supported - what would be the way for the other two bases?

**Addendum/Edit**:

Bulletproof here means that I can have nasty things in the string. The obvious thing for me is that 'G' is not a hex character. But I would have expected an appropriate error code in some way! The comparison `out.ptr != buf.end()` I've never seen in blogs (or I didn't read the right ones :)

If I enter a crazy long hex float, at least a `numerical result out of range` comes up.

By bulletproof I also mean that I can find such impossible strings by length, for example, so that I can save myself the call to `from_chars()` - for float/doubles and integers (here I would 'strlen' compare `digits10` from `std::numeric_limits`).

Comment: What do you mean by "bulletproof" here?

Comment: `G` is not an hex char, so it's OK `from_chars` reads until `G`.

Comment: Note the [return value section](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars#Return_value) in the reference you linked. What error do you expect from the posted example? Also note that the posted code already "rejects" the conversion being `out.ptr != buf.end()`.

Comment: All the standard string->number functions do this. :( Just compare if the final position is at the end of string?

Answer (score 0):

The `from_chars` utility is designed to convert the first number it finds in the string and to return a pointer to the point where it stopped.  This allows you to parse strings like `"42 centimeters"` by first converting the number and then parsing the rest of the string yourself for what comes after it.

> The comparison `out.ptr != buf.end()` I've never seen in blogs (or I didn't read the right ones :)

If you know that the entire string should be a number, then checking that the pointer in the result points to the end of the string is the normal way to ensure that `from_chars` read the entire string.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Does it mean both checks are enough? What about floating-point which is an overload for `from_chars`